# getting irrelevant values for malloc macros - M_MMAP_THRESHOLD and M_ARENA_MAX

Tags: c, malloc

Tried to print values of `M_MMAP_THRESHOLD` and `M_ARENA_MAX` in a sample `c` program :

```
  if (mallopt(M_ARENA_MAX, 0) == 0) {
      printf("mallopt() 2 failed"); 
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }   

  if (mallopt(M_MMAP_THRESHOLD, 64) == 0) {
      printf("mallopt() 2 failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  p = malloc(1000);
  if (p == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "malloc() failed");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }   
  printf("Value for M_MMAP_MAX : %d \n",M_MMAP_MAX);
  printf("Value for M_MMAP_THRESHOLD : %d \n",M_MMAP_THRESHOLD);
```

> Output:

```
Value for M_MMAP_MAX : -4 
Value for M_MMAP_THRESHOLD : -3
```

If you can suggest - how to get values for these macros.

Answer (score 1):

The macros are selectors: the value tells `mallopt` which option to set. The definition of `mallopt` (only slightly simplified) is:

```
int mallopt(int which, int value) {
    int result = 0;
    internal_lock_malloc_state();
    switch (which) {
        case M_MMAP_MAX:
            result = internal_set_maximum_mmap(value);
            break;
        case M_MMAP_THRESHOLD:
            result = internal_set_threshold(value);
            break;
        // ...
    } 
    internal_unlock_malloc_state();
    return result;
}
```

The internal functions above are probably actually written out, but that makes no difference here. The important thing is that the macro is just a small integer which indicates which option is to be modified.

Unfortunately, from your perspective, there is no way to examine the current value of these options. In fact, there is not even a guarantee that there is a current value. For example, consider an implementation of `malloc` which never uses `mmap`, perhaps because the host system doesn't implement memory mapping. Such an implementation could quite reasonably ignore any attempt to set these options, by replacing the `internal_set...` functions above with `result = 1;`.

In short, if you want to query what the current value of a malloc option is, it is up to you to remember the last value you set it to. (And there is no way to get the default value other than by reading the documentation.)

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html says that these kernel tunable parameters can be set using mallopt, then if these values are set then why not values (newly set) can be fetched using direct print or gdb info macro. Though default values are getting printed according to https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/malloc/malloc.h